# less than or more than by a certain amount

Tags: python, numbers

This game gets the user to guess a 4 digit number and gives feedback straight after the user guesses displaying 'Y' if the user gets the number right and displays 'H' if the guess is at most 3 higher than the number and obviously the opposite of displaying 'L' for at most 3 below the number. but this is my issue, i cant get it to display the 'H' and 'L' at 3 above or below! any help is appreciated.. code is below where i have attempted it.

```
from random import randint
guessesTaken = 0
randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)] # create list of random nums
while guessesTaken < 10:
    guesses = list(input("Guess Number: ")) # create list of four digits
    check = "".join(["Y" if a==b else "H" if int(a)< 3 int(b) else "L" for a, b in zip(guesses,randomNumber)])
    if check == guesses: # if check has four Y's we have a correct guess
        print("Congratulations, you are correct, it took you", guessesTaken, "guesses.")
        break
    else:
        guessesTaken += 1 # else increment guess count and ask again
        print(check)
    if guessesTaken == 10:
        print("You lose")
```

Comment: Instead of doing the `check` in one line, why not try writing out the code over multiple lines, `for a,b in zip(...):` etc. Then I think you will find the mistake more easily.

Comment: I did that but i am new to python and dont see where i have gone wrong. i cant get it to do the 3 below or above

Answer (score 0):

Repaired that, see comments.

```
from random import randint
guessesTaken = 1 # repaired that. you cannot guess correctly on "0 guesses".
randomNumber = [str(randint(1, 9))  for _ in range(4)]
while guessesTaken < 10:
        guesses = list(input("Guess Number: "))
        #repaired check cases
        check = "".join(["Y" if a == b else "L" if int(a) < int(b) and int(a)+3 >= int(b) else "H" if int(a) > int(b) and int(a)-3 <= int(b) else '?' for a, b in zip(guesses,randomNumber)])
        if check == "YYYY":  # repaired this check
            print("Congratulations, you are correct, it took you", guessesTaken, "guesses.")
            break
        else:
            guessesTaken += 1
            print(check)
else: # loop is exhausted
    print("You lose")


Guess Number: 4444
?HLH
Guess Number: 2262
?LYL
Guess Number: 7363
LYYY
Guess Number: 8363
LYYY
Guess Number: 9363
Congratulations, you are correct, it took you 5 guesses.
```

While it works, such a long list comprehension is a PITA to write and maintain.
Better keep your statements short and refactor common things out.